# Feedback on time-delayed TRIAC design

Tags: triac, delay

I would appreciate some feedback regarding the design I came up with.
While I am not unfamiliar with electronics, this is the first time I actually designed something myself.

The purpose is to solve an issue with my Land Rover / travel trainer. The car sends out every 2 seconds a short electrical pulse of 100ms length, to check if a trailer is attached and if the trailer lights are still OK. With incandescent light bulbs this works just fine, as they need a moment to light up. Our trailer however has LED light, which cause the following problems:

- The short pulse makes them flash briefly
- The car does not recognize that a trailer is attached due to the LED lights high resistance.

My design is supposed to do the following:

- V1 is the car's brake light output
- R1 simulates an incandescent light bulb, so that the car 'sees' the resistance it is expecting
- R2, 3 and C1 delay the TRIAC to turn on by around 150 ms.
- The delay of 150 ms exceeds the duration of the pulse, the brake light will therefore only turn on when the brake light is actually activated.

I simulated the circuit in LTSpice, everything seems to work just fine.

What are your thoughts?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flyP1M.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Is 1 V (V1) the amplitude of the sensing pulse, while the actual brake light voltage is 12 V?  Also, since the triac latching function is not needed, consider using a power darlington transistor or a power MOSFET instead.

Comment: At 100km/h (62mph) a car travels more than 4m (13.5 ft) in 0.15 seconds. You might have some explaining to do if someone rear-ends you and you have delayed the brake lights. "Tampered" with the brake lights is probably the term that would be used. Have you considered just using incandescent lamps?

Comment: @Spehro_Pefhany good point, but human reaction time is about 1000 ms, so 150 ms is no big deal

Comment: @AnalogKid : Oh, I did not see the 1V. The amplitude is actually 12V. I originally used a MOSFET, but dropped it as I thought the TRIAC would be a more elegant solution. I'll look into darlington transistors, as I am not familiar with them.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany : I understand that incandescent brake lights take about 200 - 300 ms to light up. Even if I introduce a delay of 150 ms, my LED lights would still turn on faster.

If possible, I would like to avoid replacing the tail lights with incandescent versions.

Comment: @Oliver Please correct your schematic by editing it rather than comments.

Comment: An R-C timer driving either a MOSFET or bipolar transistor will cause the voltage to the light to ramp up.  It will be a fast ramp, but visible.  The only advantage I see to a TRIAC or SCR is that you get a nice fast snap on, no matter how slow (within reason) the voltage ramp at the gate is.  But with a MOSFET, the size of the timing components can be greatly reduced.  Rough guess, a 150K resistor and 4.7 uF cap.

Comment: Important question - does one end of the light have to be connected to GND?  Or could the switch device go there, with the other end of the light connected directly to the switched 12V source?

Answer (score 0):

you could add a series capacitor to R1, to not ruin the power saving of the led over an old bulb.

but the thing gets complex. you want a reliable brake light, so you got led. who cares if the car does not detect the trailer?

Comment: Well, the trailer came with the LED lights, so I did not really have a choice.

Comment: If the car does not recognize the trailer, the transmission control unit will not go into towing mode. Also, the electronic stabilization needs to know about the trailer as well. If it doesn't things my become nasty, for example if the trailer starts to sway.

I like the capacitor idea and just played around with it in LTSpice. Seems like it would have to be almost 0.5F. Such a capacitor is pretty big an expensive. Not sure this is worth it, considering energy would only be wasted when I hit the brakes.

Answer (score 0):

you could try a simpler solution. just connect an inductor in series with the led.

Comment: Hi Roland, Thank you for your suggestion. I just tried this idea as well, the inductor would however have to be pretty massive.

I could install a mechanical relay. This is however something I would rather want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

As this is an electronics forum, I'd propose to avoid bulky inductors or capacitors by going to a more digital solution. Use power mosfets or darlington transistors to switch the lamp imitation resistor R1 and the led. Use some digital stuff to do the timing of 150 ms and control the fets/transistors. An Arduino board may be easy. You'd power it from a free 12V wire in the trailer cable. If you find this overkill, just look at what is inside a regular led lamp for 120 or 230 VAC: a lot of led controller and transformer stuff in one cubic centimeter for under 5 euro/dollar.

But because the application is a car to be used on public roads, I'd hesitate on this solution. How much testing do you need to guarantee safety and reliability? How about insurance coverage? How about regulations?

There are two other options, that are safer.

1) Replace the LED brake lights with old style Bulb

2) Inquire at the car dealer if the car computer can be configured to recognize the led. Perhaps an OBD setting.

If you insist on a fun electronics project, you should investigate the detection pulse system. Perhaps R1 can be larger and still be recognized as a "lamp". Perhaps the detection takes place in less than 150 ms. Perhaps the car is so smart that it looks for a resistance that increases after some milliseconds, just like a heated filament.

Comment: This is not a forum but rather strict question-answer site. You have posted three "answers". This is perhaps allowed but a clear indication that you didn't take the Tour. Can you suggest all three options in one answer perhaps?

Comment: @winny I came up with 3 totally different answers. I don't see the advantage by combining those. One might comment on answer 1, another might like to upvote answer 2, while downvoting answer 3. Perhaps I should put "Inquire at car dealer" in yet another answer? All of this in an effort to help someone with a real problem. But perhaps his true problem is not on electrical engineering

Comment: Given the second sentence of the original post, I think a microprocessor system is a pretty big leap for a first design, and massive overkill for an R-<no inductor>-C problem.